# Test Highcharts with Watir Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

i'm writing Ruby in Watir webdriver and i would like to test highcharts accuracy of data presented in comparison of a CSV file (which i already read). How can i read the highchart data from the website?
A highchart graph generated with many data dots as you mouseover the dot, a data will be  shown in a box.
I cannot locate the element using watir webdriver as what i see from source that each dot are path tags.
I am thinking maybe automate the cursor to move to a x y location but not sure how to do that. Any helps? thank you

Comment: It would help if you can give an example of the highchart you are using. Ideally it would access to the one you are testing, but it could be a similar one (eg a similar chart on the highcharts demo page).

Comment: @JustinKo Thank you for the help.here is the image link http://i.tinyuploads.com/bfRq4p.jpg

Comment: Do you need to get all of the data from the chart or how do you want to determine which data you get?

Comment: Justin did not ask for a screenshot, but for a link to a page with the chart.

Comment: @JustinKo lets say that i read the data in from a csv(which i had already did) for example wed may 29, 2013 the value should be 154,196.00. so in the graph i have to find the dot that is may 29 2013 and has that data equal to my csv. I know that it is hard to locate a dot without a id for each. Do you have a solution to this? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assumptions**

Since we only have an image of your chart, rather than the specific html, I will assume the graph is similar in design to the ["Basic Line" highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/). The below will hopefully work conceptually for your graph (ie the approach will probably work, but it will likely require some tweaks).

**Get Path Elements**

In the graph, there is a path element to draw each point, as well as a path element to draw the line.

```
<g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(62,55) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none">
  <path fill="#2f7ed8" d="M 638.25 182.5 C 643.578 182.5 643.578 190.5 638.25 190.5 C 632.922 190.5 632.922 182.5 638.25 182.5 Z"></path>
```

The g and path elements are not directly supported by watir, so you will need to use the generic element type with a css or xpath locator.

```rb
#Get the first line (as there are 4 in the demo)
series1 = browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers')

#Get the data points (the last  point is ignored since it is the line)
all_path_elements = series1.elements(:css => 'path')
points = all_path_elements[0..-2]
```

**Simulate MouseOver**

You can simulate mousing over an element using the `hover` method:

```rb
browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers path').hover
```

**Read the Popup**

The html of the popup looks like:

```
<g opacity="0" transform="translate(146,222)" visibility="hidden" style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" zIndex="8" class="highcharts-tooltip">
  <text zIndex="1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="21" x="8">
    <tspan x="8" style="font-size: 10px">Apr</tspan>
    <tspan dy="16" x="8" style="fill:#8bbc21">Berlin</tspan>
    <tspan dx="0">: </tspan>
    <tspan dx="0" style="font-weight:bold">8.4°C</tspan>
  </text>
```

We can get the text of the popup using either of the following:

```rb
#All text together
puts browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip').text
#=> "DecTokyo: 9.6°C"

#Each line of the popup
browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan').each{ |x| puts x.text }
#=> "Dec"
#=> "Tokyo"
#=> ":"
#=> "9.6°C"
```

Note that the `text` method only displays visible text, therefore you need to ensure that the popup is displayed before getting the text. Alternatively you could parse the html of the elements.

**Search the Data Points**

To find the value (ex temperature) for the specific date, we need to iterate over the path elements until we find one that matches the desired date. Using the `points` variable from before, let us get the value for July.

```rb
point = points.find do |p|  
  #Hover over a point
  p.hover

  #Get the month from the popup
  month = browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan')[0].text

  #Keep going until the month is "Jul"
  month == 'Jul'
end

#Get the value of the point
point.hover
puts browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan')[3].text
#=> "25.2°C"
```

This value could then be compared to the spreadsheet of expected values.

**Running Script**

Putting all the points together, gives the final running example.

```rb
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto 'http://www.highcharts.com/demo/'
series1 = browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers')
all_path_elements = series1.elements(:css => 'path')
points = all_path_elements[0..-2]
point = points.find do |p|  
  p.hover
  month = browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan')[0].text
  month == 'Jul'
end
point.hover
puts browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan')[3].text
#=> "25.2°C"
```

Comment: Sorry i was out for few days. Thank you soooo much!! You solved this for me. You are amazing , seriously that testing was giving me hard time. Thank you!!

Comment: this only works in chrome not ie or firefox.:css => 'g.highcharts-markers' error in ie. elements_by_xpath': undefined method `ole_object' u have ways to make it work also in ie and firefox? thanks

Comment: The script runs fine for me in Firefox v21. For Firefox v22, it stops working. Likely, you will need to wait for a new selenium-webdriver version that supports v22.

Comment: For IE, the script will not work due to the graph being rendered differently. However, even fixing those issues, the script still does not work. I do not see an obvious fix.

Comment: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component  (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError). this error i got with V21. weird

Comment: Are you using the latest selenium-webdriver version (2.33)?

Comment: im using testwise. not sure not version it is. maybe ur right. its my driver issue. i try to run it without the ide and see. BTW, u can hover the data point but can u click on the points. i tried point.click and got error- Element is not clickable at point (760.2874145507812, 577.5). Other element would receive the click: undefined

Comment: browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers') gets the first line, how about getting the second line or third?. i tried browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers',:index=>2) didnt work. element only support the first occurance? BTW just to let you know i have figure out a way to click on the point. by click(:control) holding ctrl and click works :)

Comment: It looks like you cannot combine :css and :index locators. To get the second one do `browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers')[1]` or `browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-markers:nth-child(1)')`

Comment: hi do u have a good way for pie charts? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic
I tried looping through the pie, sometimes it will miss one piece because that piece is tiny. it is weird that i got all the information on the demo but not my own chart.

Comment: all_path_elements[-2..-2] i am missing the last to second piece. i tried with -1..-1 will print the last one and -2..-2 still last one. and -3..-3 the third from last. it is weird. maybe u cannot locate tiny piece?

Comment: @PeterZDE, comments are not good format for asking/solving complex problems. I think you should create a new question so that you can share what you have and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Hard to calculate the number of hours you just saved me.