# Testing Highcharts Line Charts Data Points using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, highcharts

I've seen this issue answered using Watir Webdriver to test a highcharts line charts here [Test Highcharts with Watir Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114495/test-highcharts-with-watir-webdriver). However, I cannot seem to solve it using my test framework with selenium webdriver and css / xpath locators.

I am using python with selenium webdriver in an attempt to browse through data points of a line chart similar to that seen at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/. My chart is a TIme based chart with a line and bar chart in one. I have hidden the bar chart for test purposes so as to view only the line chart. I'm trying to use the mouse over functionality to display the tooltip for each data point on my chart, and theN extract the data shown.

This is working fine for other formatted charts (bar/pie/donut) as each data item is seen as a separate highcharts-series but the line chart seems to be a single highcharts-series with a single path element containing the element d = all the data points.

I can not find a way to browse through all the data points within my line shown. My line chart contains 1 single data series with 24 points (each hour of the day)

The html code I'm working with is:

```
<g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
    <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker" visibility="hidden" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(91,55) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(#highcharts-7)">
        <rect fill="#497646" x="364.5" y="192.5" width="12" height="258" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="hidden" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(91,55) scale(1 1)">
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(55,55) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-7)">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#aa4643" stroke-width="2" zIndex="1" d="M 12.708333333333334 451 C 12.708333333333334 451 27.958333333333332 451 38.125 451 C 48.29166666666667 451 53.375 451 63.54166666666667 451 C 73.70833333333333 451 78.79166666666667 451 88.95833333333333 451 C 99.125 451 104.20833333333333 451 114.375 451 C 124.54166666666667 451 129.625 451 139.79166666666669 451 C 149.95833333333334 451 155.04166666666669 451 165.20833333333334 451 C 175.375 451 180.45833333333334 451 190.62500000000003 451 C 200.79166666666669 451 205.875 451 216.04166666666669 451 C 226.20833333333334 451 231.29166666666669 451 241.45833333333334 451 C 251.625 451 256.70833333333337 451 266.875 451 C 277.0416666666667 451 282.125 451 292.2916666666667 451 C 302.4583333333333 451 307.5416666666667 451 317.7083333333333 451 C 327.875 451 332.9583333333333 451 343.125 451 C 353.2916666666667 451 358.375 25.7 368.5416666666667 25.7 C 378.7083333333333 25.7 383.7916666666667 451 393.9583333333333 451 C 404.125 451 409.2083333333333 451 419.375 451 C 429.5416666666667 451 434.625 451 444.7916666666667 451 C 454.9583333333333 451 460.0416666666667 451 470.2083333333333 451 C 480.375 451 485.4583333333333 451 495.625 451 C 505.7916666666667 451 510.875 451 521.0416666666667 451 C 531.2083333333334 451 536.2916666666667 451 546.4583333333334 451 C 556.625 451 561.7083333333334 451 571.8750000000001 451 C 582.0416666666667 451 597.2916666666667 451 597.2916666666667 451"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(55,55) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none">
        <path fill="#aa4643" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden" d="M 368.5416666666667 19.7 C 376.5336666666667 19.7 376.5336666666667 31.7 368.5416666666667 31.7 C 360.54966666666667 31.7 360.54966666666667 19.7 368.5416666666667 19.7 Z"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker" fill="none" d="M 2.708333333333334 451 L 12.708333333333334 451 C 12.708333333333334 451 27.958333333333332 451 38.125 451 C 48.29166666666667 451 53.375 451 63.54166666666667 451 C 73.70833333333333 451 78.79166666666667 451 88.95833333333333 451 C 99.125 451 104.20833333333333 451 114.375 451 C 124.54166666666667 451 129.625 451 139.79166666666669 451 C 149.95833333333334 451 155.04166666666669 451 165.20833333333334 451 C 175.375 451 180.45833333333334 451 190.62500000000003 451 C 200.79166666666669 451 205.875 451 216.04166666666669 451 C 226.20833333333334 451 231.29166666666669 451 241.45833333333334 451 C 251.625 451 256.70833333333337 451 266.875 451 C 277.0416666666667 451 282.125 451 292.2916666666667 451 C 302.4583333333333 451 307.5416666666667 451 317.7083333333333 451 C 327.875 451 332.9583333333333 451 343.125 451 C 353.2916666666667 451 358.375 25.7 368.5416666666667 25.7 C 378.7083333333333 25.7 383.7916666666667 451 393.9583333333333 451 C 404.125 451 409.2083333333333 451 419.375 451 C 429.5416666666667 451 434.625 451 444.7916666666667 451 C 454.9583333333333 451 460.0416666666667 451 470.2083333333333 451 C 480.375 451 485.4583333333333 451 495.625 451 C 505.7916666666667 451 510.875 451 521.0416666666667 451 C 531.2083333333334 451 536.2916666666667 451 546.4583333333334 451 C 556.625 451 561.7083333333334 451 571.8750000000001 451 C 582.0416666666667 451 597.2916666666667 451 597.2916666666667 451 L 607.2916666666667 451" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-opacity="0.0001" stroke="rgb(192,192,192)" stroke-width="22" zIndex="2" style="" visibility="visible"></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
BazScal

Comment: what code are you trying ? Also, I believe, this is not the complete html as I work with highcharts myself.

Comment: I'm coding in python and using selenium webdriver to access the UI that contains a highchart bar / line combination chart. The inserted html code that I am attempting to access. The problem I'm having is that for each item on the line, there is no separate path for each data point along the line.

Comment: Is that possible to loop through all points as javascript objects instead of getting them from DOM? This has been changed to put in one element for better performance. For example `chart.series[0].data[0].graphic` will access to DOM element, so you should be able to call something like hover for that exact point.

Comment: That's the trouble I'm having, each point only becomes "active" when I hover the mouse over it and the path content changes. In the highcharts line demo chart, each point or html path is shown as a separate element. In my example, as you mention @PawełFus the class path element for my line chart is one adjustable path element, adjusting upon a mouse over. I tried going down to route of using xy offsets but these charts will be dynamic to processed data so they will not always show the same content. Maybe you are right, looking into looping through the points when activated by a hover action.

Comment: did you get the solution validation of line charts? I am facing the same issue. I couldn't get how to mouse over there.